# Do sefardim have to check rice for Hametz nowadays?

Tags: halacha, passover, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, inspection, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

Rav Y. Abadi holds that nowadays, there is no need to check our rice for pieces of Hametz due to the way rice is manufactured. 
http://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=11648&highlight=

Are there any other mainstream Rabbanim who hold simmilar views?

Comment: Note: some rice nowadays is enriched with vitamins and such from wheat. Caveat emptor!

Comment: This question appears to be assuming that the default view is that rice must be checked. If that's right, then it'd be nice if it said so.

Comment: http://www.jsor.org/Rice2014_RevA.pdf

Comment: @msh210 the minhag is to check each grain of rice piece by piece. my mother erev pesach used to sit for hours checking each grain.

Comment: +1 Rav Abadi is a brilliant and pious posek, and he doesn't need anyone else to agree with him in order to rely on him.

Answer (score -1):

I have  noticed some Persian Jews in Jerusalem check their rice so carefully one by one, that any grain of rice that is broken is discarded, because it may not be easy to differentiate from a piece of other grain.